# How to use a return variable in a $this

Tags: php, variables

I have a sub class that contains getDbIDFieldName. The function purpose is to return the actual variable name of the primary key of this current model.

```
public function getDbIdFieldName(){ return "permission_id"; }
```

In the main class `BaseModel` I have the following functions setId and getId. I am currently trying to use these function to set/get the primary key of the sub class.

example:

```
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->strVal($this->getDbIdFieldName()) = $id;
}
```

The problem is this is invalid. I tried multiple things but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: you can't assign a value to an expression. it's like doing `1 + 1 = 3`.

Comment: `$id = $this->strVal($this->getDbIdFieldName());`

Comment: @RonakPatel I dont think so. @OP: It's probably more like `$this->values[ $this->getDbIdFieldName() ] = $id`?

Comment: @MarcB AFAIK there was a PHP version (5.3 or so) that allowed to return refs from a function.

Comment: @ken: but that still doesn't allow you to ASSIGN a value to that function call.

Comment: @MarcB What should I be doing? I want to have a generic getId and setId that can be used from all my sub classes.

Comment: then use the magic __get() and __set() methods.

Comment: You could also just do `$this->id = $id` in your `setId()`, and only use `getDbIdFieldName()` when you construct SQL.

Comment: @Kenney not all model has the primary key as `id`

Comment: @JoshuaDalley I understand. But you know it has a PK. It only matters to use the right name when you do SQL queries.

Comment: You could do the array thing Kenney mentioned a few comments up: `$this->values[ $this->getDbIdFieldName() ] = $id` if you make `$values` be an array.

Comment: Just an FYI, PHP is not like C++, you cannot return lvalue references. Functions always return rvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a temporary variable:

```
public function setId($id) {
    $tmp = $this->getDbIdFieldName();
    $this->{$tmp} = $id;
}
```

See an example [here](https://eval.in/472215).